# SQL GROUP_CONCAT in subquery does not give the desired data

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

im trying to select data with a subquery.
If i run the subquery without the other stuff around it works as expected,
otherwise it returns only data from 1 row and not 4.

```
SELECT t.IDS,
(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(_t.DATA SEPARATOR ';')
    FROM table _t
    WHERE _t.ID IN (t.IDS)
) as DATA
FROM (
    SELECT '1,2,3,4' as IDS
) t;
```

Table:

| ID | DATA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Test |
| 2 | Test1 |
| 3 | Test2 |
| 4 | Test3 |

The query should return this:
IDS: '1,2,3,4'
DATA: 'Test;Test1;Test2;Test3'

Currently it returns this:
IDS: '1,2,3,4'
DATA: 'Test'

The query above is only an example.

Comment: What ***is*** the desired result?

Comment: the result should look like this: Test;Test1;Test2;Test3

Comment: You have `WHERE _t.ID IN ('1,2,3,4')`, but there is no row with an `ID = '1,2,3,4'`. So, it is not surprising you are getting no result.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner 
with `_t.ID IN (t.IDS)` i want to get the same result as `_t.ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4)`
thats the current problem

Comment: You are creating one t row with '1,2,3,4'. If you create four rows with 1, 2, 3, and 4 instead, you'll have the data set you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table t is a string so that `IN` doesn't work, but you can use `FIND_IN_SET`instead, but the peromance is bad.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1 (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `DATA` VARCHAR(5)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tab1
>   (`ID`, `DATA`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'Test'),
>   ('2', 'Test1'),
>   ('3', 'Test2'),
>   ('4', 'Test3');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t.IDS,
> (
>     SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(_t.DATA  ORDER BY _t.ID SEPARATOR ';')
>     FROM tab1 _t
>     WHERE FIND_IN_SET(_t.ID,t.IDS)
> ) as DATA
> FROM (
>     SELECT '1,2,3,4' as IDS
> ) t;
> ```
>
> ```
> IDS     | DATA                  
> :------ | :---------------------
> 1,2,3,4 | Test;Test1;Test2;Test3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b231df20ae5e71a77c722f0e2d26cd6e)*